# Save view in code and access it remotly

Tags: views

I am trying to achieve two things
I have 4 sites all with the same shared docroot code.

3 sites are of deferent sections in the company (we'll call them sec_1,sec_2,sec_3) and one site is the main admin site (internal site for me as an admin to monitor some things)

1) I created a view for a list of all users of certain roles on my site, and I would like to save it in code, so every site sec_1, sec_2, sec_3 will have this view. By saving this in code i'll be able to create more sec_x sites that will have this view in the future.

Any ideas how to do so? View's export does not seem like the right way to go about this.

2) I would like to expose the result of the view to the admin site, so I can present all lists in one page of the admin site.
I was thinking on something like this

```
$test = drupal_http_request('http://sec_1_URL/my_view');
```

but this results in

```
[code] => 403
[error] => Forbidden
```

Comment: Why not use Features for this? https://www.drupal.org/project/features

Comment: @Kevin, can you include a view in a feature? How do you address the 2nd issue with a feature ?

Comment: Yes, anything exportable can be put into a Feature. Just re-export the Feature and send that updated module to sites needing the View(s), voila, updated.

Comment: @kevin thanks that will solve issue 1, but what about the remote access to the results ?

Comment: That is a separate issue from saving View config in code

Comment: Any ideas on that one or should I split those to two different questions?